# How to customize TFS work item alert email

Tags: tfs

I'm using TFS2018 and I'm trying to customize the contents of the work item alert emails.

I've tried following the instructions on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/setup-customize-alerts?view=tfs-2018) to edit the WorkItemChangedEvent.xsl file. However I found that under the  folder there is both a WorkItemChangedEvent.xsl file and a WorkItemChangedEvent_2.xsl file. I tried modifying both of these files and restarting the application pool, but the changes don't seem to take effect. Then I even tried removing the WorkItemChangedEvent.xsl file by renaming it, and found that the email alerts are still working without the file. I then tried removing the WorkItemChangedEvent_2.xsl file and found that alerts stopped working. So I concluded that the actual file required is WorkItemChangedEvent_2.xsl instead of WorkItemChangedEvent.xsl. However, I then tried to put in an empty file named WorkItemChangedEvent_2.xsl, and the alerts started working again. So now I am very puzzled. It seems like the system only requires there to be a file named WorkItemChangedEvent_2.xsl in existence in order for alerts to work, and the actual contents of the file do not matter. So where is the system actually getting the email formatting from? What do I need to do to customize my work item alert emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some more tests we also reproduce your scenario and generated the same WorkItemChangedEvent_2.xsl. The files are totally different for both, such as `WorkItemChangedEvent_2.xsl` has 134KB, `WorkItemChangedEvent.xsl` only has 21KB. However, after go through MSDN and related official  links, we didn't find any doc include detail explanations why there are two files.

Unlike your side, if we change `WorkItemChangedEvent_2.xsl`, it work properly and e-mail alert format get updated. We also restart [TFS background Job agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/architecture/background-job-agent?view=azure-devops) service during the process.

In case you have lost the content in WorkItemChangedEvent_2.xsl, share this file [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtdSbH1PdTBciyvxWoQ9xChbQanN?e=h6k6KZ). You could try to download and modify in your local, test again.

If you still get stuck with this, you could also use below workarounds.

Create your own extension or use some 3rd-party extension  to handle this situation. Such as this [TfsNotificationRelay](https://github.com/kria/TfsNotificationRelay) include below features:

- Notify multiple targets
- Rule-based event filtering
- Regex filtering on collection, project, repository, branch etc.
- **Configurable notification format**
- Notification links back to event in TFS web
- Extensible to support other targets

Another option is subscribing to TFS events via API, this method gives the option to set email subject you want. Check this blog for further information:　http://geekswithblogs.net/BobHardister/archive/2013/07/24/tfs-2012-api-create-alert-subscriptions.aspx (The blog is written for TFS2012, similar to TFS2018 as well)

---

> The event service uses the `.xsl` and the `plaintextXsl` files to
>   transform the XML data for an event into an e-mail message. Edit the
>   .xsl file to get a different format for the email notification. For
>   HTML-formatted email messages, the core layout for all events is
>   stored in TeamFoundation.xsl. You should make a backup copy of any
>   files that you want to change, and then test your changes. After you
>   have made your changes, TFS will use the modified transform the next
>   time it generates a notification for an event.

WorkItemChangedEvent_2.xsl this will only effect HTML  e-mail, first check if you are **receiving a HTML e-mail**.

The content of the emails that are issued is automatically generated from the **TeamFoundation.xsl** file and the above WorkItemChangedEvent xsl files.

So if you want to customize detail content, please also change `TeamFoundation.xsl` related part.

However, note modifying the TeamFoundation.xsl file is not recommended. If you do modify the contents of this file, you must thoroughly test your modifications. Incorrect modifications of this file can result in the failure of TFS email alerts and cause you to be unable to view work items, changesets, or files in a Web browser.

Comment: I am receiving HTML e-mail. In fact, I don't see a way in TFS 2018 to change the setting to receive plain text emails.

My question still remains then -- how come the alerts still work with a missing WorkItemChangedEvent.xsl file and an empty WorkItemChangedEvent_2.xsl file?

In any case, I will try editing the TeamFoundation.xsl file also and see where that takes me. Thanks!

Comment: I looked at the TeamFoundation.xsl file and it doesn't seem to me that the statement "the core layout for all events is stored in TeamFoundation.xsl" is true in TFS2018. I don't see anything in there that would apply to the WorkItemChangedEvent. The only things defined in there are some variables and the following templates (most of them are TFVC-related): addReferrer, footer, link, style, TeamFoundationItem, TeamFoundationShelvedItem, CheckinEvent, ShelvesetEvent, wiItem, and Exception. What do I need to edit to change the core layout of the WorkItemChangedEvent?

Comment: @ttplaya Sorry for the later reply due to holiday. Have updated my answer also include two workaround. Please kindly check it.

Comment: Thank you -- what I was missing was to restart the TFS Background Agent Job service. After I restarted the service I started seeing the effects of my changes! Please make sure this missing key piece of information is added to the doc page I linked to in my OP.